# Use DAX to get data between 2 tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table 'tblA' with only 1 column named 'Value'

```
Value
1
2
```

The second table 'tblB' with several columns

```
Col1 Col2
Test A
Dump B
```

How can I have a join between them so that I will have new table with result like this (each value in tblA will fill in to all rows in tblB):

```
Col1 Col2 Value
Test A     1
Dump B     1
Test A     2
Dump B     2
```

I also tried to use for loop to get one-by-one value in tblA. But it seems that DAX didn't support loop.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expression for a **calculated table**

tblC = CROSSJOIN ( tblA, tblB )